# Using Bootstrap-vue in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I figured out bootstrap-vue in Vue 3 application.
But it doesn't work properly, for instance, I tried to use a b-carousel, but it showed nothing.

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import Vue from 'vue'

import { BootstrapVue } from 'bootstrap-vue'

createApp(App).use(router).use(BootstrapVue).mount('#app')
```

Comment: A suggestion: Learn to use `tailwindcss` instead of bootstrap-vue, I belive Vue 3 does not support `bootstrap-vue` because it will be deprecated soon, when you used to use tailwind you will not back to bootstrap

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.